# New driver installation on Windows

Tags: windows, windows-7, kernel

I am trying to find what happens when new driver is installed for windows. (What kernel data structures are modified.) Does anyone know any good documentation on this topic. It is a bit painful to debug this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a driver is installed is it placed into the Driver Store (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff544868%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

When a new device is discovered that does not have a current driver association the PNP manager looks at the driver store to see if any of the stored drivers will match the new device.

If the PNP manager finds a driver to match the device it will execute the directives in the drivers inf file. This typically creates a service entry in the registry (**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services**), copies the driver binaries to somewhere like **\Windows\System32\drivers** etc. Also the PNP manager will create an association of that device to that driver (**HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum** I think) so that next time it can shortcut the process.

I don't think any kernel data structures are modified when a driver is installed. Do you mean to ask when a driver is loaded?

Comment: I was wondering if IDT changes with new driver. There could be a case where prologue does not change and just new epilogue is registered with new driver. However, if IDT is changing then a new value must be required to be loaded in IDTR.

Comment: @agent.smith: I suggest you ask that at http://www.osronline.com/showlists.cfm?list=ntdev they are more knowledgeable on this subject then I